# Is it possible to change a string color in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()

Tags: java, colors, joptionpane

So i have this code, which opens a `JOptionPane` with information about the exception:

```
String fileName=e.getStackTrace()[0].getFileName();
String methodName=e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
String line=String.valueOf(e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel("There was an unexpected "+e+" at file: "+fileName+" in method: "+methodName+" in line: "+line));
```

The only thing i am not happy with is the fact that its all the same color, so i thought why not change the color of the Strings regarding the exception to red. So i googled a bit and found several similar question on SO, and also tried what they suggested there with html-tags and such, but i was not successful. Is there any working way to color the text? Currently it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/6EwRA) with html tags

Comment: Have you tried doing `"<html><font color='COLOR'>"` before the exception and `"</font></html>"` after the exception?

Comment: yes, the string as you posted is appears now inside the message box

Comment: Just to make sure, you are writing like this:

`"There was an unexpected " + "<html><font color='red'>" + e + "</font></html>"`?

I just tested it out and it worked for me.

Comment: this code: `new JLabel("There was an unexpected " + "<html><font color='red'>" + e + "</font></html>"+" at file: "+fileName+" in method: "+methodName+" in line: "+line));` does not work for me

Comment: I'm really at a loss here. Do you have a picture of the output after you use the html?

Comment: added a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire string needs to be enclosed within the HTML tags. [For more information, see How to Use HTML in Swing Components.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)